# Struggling with parsing if statements and code layout in Haskell

Tags: if-statement, haskell

The code here is nonsense and I know it, I don't want a different solution to this problem because this is just to highlight my issue not the actual goal. This is my code:

```
example x
    if x == 2 then "Input is 2"
        else if x > 2 then if x == 3 then "Input is 3"
                else "Input is greater than 3"
            else "Dunno"
        else "Dunno"
```

My intended input -> output is:

```
-- input
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 
-- output
["Dunno", "Dunno", "Input is 2", "Input is 3", "Input is greater than 3"]
```

I'm having a hard time getting started with Haskell I'm finding the formatting of if's and else a lot less intuitive than Python.

Comment: `if`s, etc. are usually written with guards.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem would you be as kind to type this code out with guards?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem True, but we can nest `if`s, while we can not nest guards. (That being said, deeply nested `if`s usually are a code smell.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you was very close, you only forgot an equals sign (`=`) at the start:

```
example x = if x == 2 then "Input is 2"
        else if x > 2 then if x == 3 then "Input is 3"
                else "Input is greater than 3"
            else "Dunno"
```

In Haskell, one does not often use `if…then…else…`. Usually *guards* are used, or pattern matching. Here a more elegant way to write it with a combination of pattern matching and guards is:

```
example :: Int -> String
example 2 = "Input is 2"
example 3 = "Input is 3"
example x | x > 3 = "Input is greater than 3"
          | otherwise = "Dunno"
```

I think it makes it more clear what logic is performed here. Basically every line covers a case, on the left side of the `=`, we see the condition, on the right side, we see the result.

Comment: I know it tells me not to just comment "Thanks" but thank-you so much :)

Answer (score 5):

You can format it like you would in Python, indenting each level of nesting:

```
example x =
    if x == 2 then
        "Input is 2"
    else
        if x > 2 then
            if x == 3 then
                "Input is 3"
            else
                "Input is greater than 3"
        else
            "Dunno"
    else
        "Dunno"
```

At that point, it becomes obvious that it doesn’t make any sense, because there are more `else`s than `if`s.

But you don’t usually nest that many `if`s in Haskell anyway, since pattern matching and guards exist.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that we need to keep the `if`s as they are, I would use this indentation

```
if condition
then result1
else result2
```

resulting in

```
example x =
    if x == 2
    then "Input is 2"
    else if x > 2
         then if x == 3
              then "Input is 3"
              else "Input is greater than 3"
         else "Dunno"
```

(Note: I removed the additional `else "Dunno"` found in the original code, since it is a mistake)

Alternatively:

```
example x =
    if x == 2 then
       "Input is 2"
    else if x > 2 then
       if x == 3 then
          "Input is 3"
       else
          "Input is greater than 3"
    else
       "Dunno"
```

is also nice since it avoids the "staircase effect", where indentation keeps increasing. This is because we follow the scheme

```
if condition1 then
   result1
else if condition2 then
   result2
else if condition3 then
   result3
...
else
   resultN
```

Of course, for this specific example I would actually use guards and pattern matching instead.

```
example 2 = "Input is 2"
example 3 = "Input is 3"
example x
   | x > 2 = "Input is greater than 3"
   | otherwise = "Dunno"
```

(possibly readjusting the `x > 2` to `x > 3`, which is equivalent on integers, but more readable here)